# Crystal Reports Running Total Field Formula

Tags: crystal-reports

```
WhileReadingRecords;
numbervar ContadorVenda=0;
IF {RELATORIO_ANGLO.tp_movimento} = "V" THEN
    ContadorVenda:=ContadorVenda+1;
```

How do I make this formula to show the value of "ContadorVenda" on the report ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a ContadorVenda; at the end. Like so:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
numbervar ContadorVenda=0;
IF {RELATORIO_ANGLO.tp_movimento} = "V" THEN
    ContadorVenda:=ContadorVenda+1;

ContadorVenda;
```

Comment: Still not working .. It's supposed to run all the fields in the table RELATORIO_ANGLO and look for V's but it's like it's not counting..

Comment: The formula has to be on a detail section